# Clearing ListView items create duplicate items when using events

Tags: c#, listview, winapi, events, listviewitem

I have a list view that I want to be able to clear from items and then fill it up again.
I need to use it with events to my `Engine` class.

The problem starts when I clear the items and run it again, it duplicate my items:
[image]

Any idea why it happens and how to solve it?
Clearing the list view or initialize new list view doesn't work for me.

My Form code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private delegate void createListViewCallBack(string i_File, string i_FileStatus);
        private void createListView(string i_File, string i_FileStatus)
        {

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                createListViewCallBack s = new createListViewCallBack(createListView);
                this.Invoke(s, i_File, i_FileStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(i_File);
                item.SubItems.Add(i_FileStatus);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }


        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Engine.BuildListViewUpdate += Engine_BuildListViewUpdate;
            Engine.BuildList();
            //createListView(@"c:\a.txt", @"yes");
            //createListView(@"c:\b.txt", @"no");
        }


        private delegate void buildListUpdateCallBack(string i_File, string i_FileStatus);
        private void Engine_BuildListViewUpdate(string i_File, string i_FileStatus)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                buildListUpdateCallBack s = new buildListUpdateCallBack(Engine_BuildListViewUpdate);
                this.Invoke(s, i_File, i_FileStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(i_File);
                item.SubItems.Add(i_FileStatus);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void clear1()
        {
            this.listView1 = new ListView();
            //this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            //this.columnHeader1,
            //this.columnHeader2});
            this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
            this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 156);
            this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
            this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(633, 265);
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        }

        private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            //listView1.Clear();
            //clear1();
        }
    }
}
```

My Engine class:

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public delegate void BuildListViewEventHandler(string i_File, string i_FileStatus);
    static class Engine
    {
        public static event BuildListViewEventHandler BuildListViewUpdate;

        public static void BuildList()
        {
            BuildListViewUpdate(@"c:\a.txt", @"yes");
            BuildListViewUpdate(@"c:\b.txt", @"no");
        }

        public static void OnBuildListViewUpdate(string i_File, string i_FileStatus)
        {
            if (BuildListViewUpdate != null)
            {
                BuildListViewUpdate.Invoke(i_File, i_FileStatus);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are subscribing to the event every time you click start.

So the second time you click the start button the event will fire twice and so on.

To fix it subscribe to the event only once at the start of your program or unsubscribe when clearing the list

```
private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    Engine.BuildListViewUpdate -= Engine_BuildListViewUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it make sense to use the `-=` inside the start button function? like that:
`private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  { Engine.BuildListViewUpdate -= Engine_BuildListViewUpdate; Engine.BuildListViewUpdate += Engine_BuildListViewUpdate; Engine.BuildList(); }`

Comment: It will for sure work, but it beats the event's Purpose. when using an Event, you want to subscribe only when you really need to and unsubscribe whenever you don't need the event again. Otherwise, you will be better off using a normal function call.  (In your case I would subscribe only once at the start of the program and unsubscribe at end of the program)